# WSo2 Identity Server : User self-registration via my account

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

Source : https://lms.wso2.com/courses/take/wso2-identity-server-fundamentals-v5-11/pdfs/22647862-practical-exercise-user-management

After following "LAB02 : User self-registration via my account" as mentioned in the source, I get the error mentioned in the screenshot and also corresponding deployment.toml can be seen in the screenshot. How to fix this error?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the ERROR traces in your terminal, your `deployment.toml` file contains some keys more than once.
eg: ERROR {org.wso2.config.mapper.TomlParser} - server previously defined at line 1, column 1 (line 79, column 1) means [server] configs are in the  `deployment.toml` at line 1 and line 79.

You can't define the same key (eg: [server]) more than once in the `deployment.toml` file.
Check other ERRORs and remove the redundant configs.

You can find more details about toml configs by:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRWvtcV1T94&t=695s
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WqZhUoK77I

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anuradha.

The above error message comes from Docker.
To keep things simple :
Today, I installed WSO2 in Windows.
Disable two factor authentication in GMAIL.
Enabled less secure app in GMAIL.
The source documentation worked as it is.